# Ionic - redirect state nested under tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I make the button in the contact tab properly redirect to “tabs.facts”

Given these states:

```
.state('tabs.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.facts', {
  url: "/facts",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.contact', {
  url: "/contact",
  views: {
    'contact-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
    }
  }
});
```

And this button on the `/contact` page

```
<button class="button" ui-sref="tabs.facts">
  Go to scientific facts!
</button>
```

How can I get this button to properly redirect, preserving the proper view history? You can see how it doesn't work by clicking the button here (go to the contact page): http://codepen.io/jtmarmon/pen/qZPRLX

Answer (score 1):

This is because the named view `contact-tab` for `tabs.contact` is different from `home-tab`. If you have had them under same named view, they would have had the correct navigation. If you use href instead of ui-sref, it would work fine:

```
<button class="button" href="#/facts">
  Go to scientific facts!
</button>
```